# SQL Server Formatmessage function unable to work with a variable within a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Data setup to explain my problem

```
    create table dbo.tbl_test1(
        test1_id    int,
        val         varchar(50)
    );

    create table dbo.tbl_test2(
        test2_id    int,
        val         varchar(50)
    );

    insert into dbo.tbl_test1 values(1, 'Hola');    
    insert into dbo.tbl_test2 values(1, 'Hi');
```

Following procedure when invoked throws error as shown in the screen shot

```
create procedure [dbo].[test_procedure] 
   @tbl_nm varchar(50), 
   @col_nm varchar(50), 
   @val varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @sqlPartial as nvarchar(max),
            @sqlTmp as nvarchar(max),
            @result as int

    SET @sqlPartial = 'select @res=%s from %s where val=''%s'''
    /* @sqlPartial as argument is source of error */
    SELECT @sqlTmp=FORMATMESSAGE(@sqlPartial, @col_nm, @tbl_nm, @val)
    print @sqlTmp

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlTmp, N'@res int OUTPUT', @res=@result OUTPUT

    select @result
end
go
```

[image]

It seems FORMATMESSAGE is unable to work with variable @sqlPartial.
As soon as I replace @sqlPartial with the string from @sqlPartial, it works well like in following modified procedure

```
alter procedure [dbo].[test_procedure] 
   @tbl_nm varchar(50), 
   @col_nm varchar(50), 
   @val varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @sqlTmp as nvarchar(max),
            @result as int
    /* @sqlPartial replaced with content works */
    SELECT @sqlTmp = FORMATMESSAGE('select @res=%s from %s where val=''%s''', @col_nm, @tbl_nm, @val)
    print @sqlTmp

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlTmp, N'@res int OUTPUT', @res=@result OUTPUT

    select @result
end
go
```

To execute this procedure use

```
exec dbo.test_procedure @tbl_nm='tbl_test1', @col_nm='test1_id', @val='Hola'
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: have you tried declaring @SqlPartial as nvarchar(xxx) and not nvarchar(max) ????

it seems like FORMATMESSAGE can handle 2048 chars maximum and maybe it hase issues with the nvarchar(max) ? 

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: cannot reproduce your error

Comment: @Antonio - I tried just now, first with 2048 and then with 250, no luck

Comment: @StepUp - Does this mean you are able to get output from the first version of procedure? If so what version of SQL-Server are you using? Mine is 
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64) 
 Aug 15 2017 10:23:29 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: My version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU14) (KB4484710) - 14.0.3076.1 (X64)   Mar 12 2019 19:29:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're below 2017 (or is it 2016?), you can't use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` with `FORMATMESSAGE`, it's a system function actually used for reporting errors and so it has its limitations. You can use `NVARCHAR(4000)` (the max amount) though.

[image: results on SQL Server 2012]

Comment: Indeed, changing nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(4000) worked. But then it had to be changed for both '@sqlPartial', '@sqlTmp'. Just changing it for '@sqlPartial' which was supplied to FORMATMESSAGE doesn't work.

Comment: That's exaclty the same solution I gave you, to change nvarchar(max) to something else...does it only work with nvarchar(4000) ?